# Array manupulation in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array of commands

```
COMMANDS=('subsystem1 reload' 'subsystem2 reload' 'subsystem3 reload')
```

`subsystem1`, `subsystem2` and `subsystem3` are my subsystems.

I also have a string which contains currently loaded subsystems, for example:

```
"subsystem1,subsystem2"
```

My goal is to remove command of unloaded subsystems from `COMMANDS` array. In this case `COMMANDS` array must be

```
COMMANDS=('subsystem1 reload' 'subsystem2 reload').
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: thanks Mat for correction

Comment: Please check the expected result. I doubt you need subsystem1 twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern matching to search for a subsystem in the list of loaded subsystems.

```
#! /bin/bash
commands=('subsystem1 reload' 'subsystem2 reload' 'subsystem3 reload')
loaded='subsystem1,subsystem2';

new_commands=()
for c in "${commands[@]}" ; do
    subsystem=${c%% *}
    if [[ $loaded, == *$subsystem,* ]] ; then
        new_commands+=("$c")
    fi
done

for c in "${new_commands[@]}" ; do
    echo "$c"
done
```

More robust approach would be to use associative arrays (bash 4 needed):

```
#! /bin/bash
commands=('subsystem1 reload' 'subsystem2 reload' 'subsystem3 reload')
loaded='subsystem1,subsystem2';

declare -A loaded_a
IFS_=$IFS
IFS=,
for subsystem in $loaded ; do
    loaded_a[$subsystem]=1
done
IFS=$IFS_

new_commands=()
for c in "${commands[@]}" ; do
    subsystem=${c%% *}
    if [[ ${loaded_a[$subsystem] } ]] ; then
        new_commands+=("$c")
    fi
done

for c in "${new_commands[@]}" ; do
    echo "$c"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work:

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMANDS=('subsystem1 reload' 'subsystem2 reload' 'subsystem3 reload')
SUBSYSTEMS="subsystem1,subsystem2"

for i in $(seq ${#COMMANDS[@]} -1 1); do
  unset found

  OLDIFS=$IFS
  IFS=','
  for subsys in $SUBSYSTEMS; do
    [[ ${COMMANDS[$i-1]} =~ $subsys ]] && found="y"
  done
  IFS=$OLDIFS

  [ -z "$found" ] && unset COMMANDS[$i-1]
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the valid commands to an array, loop between both, and use pattern matching to check if one command begins with the required stirng

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMANDS=('subsystem1 reload' 'subsystem2 reload' 'subsystem3 reload')
valid="subsystem1,subsystem2"

IFS="\"," validArr=($valid);

for comm in "${COMMANDS[@]}"
do
    for val in "${validArr[@]}"
    do
        if [[ $comm == ${val}* ]]
        then
            result+=("$comm")
        fi
    done
done
COMMANDS=("${result[@]}")
printf "%s\n" "${COMMANDS[@]}"
```